# IIS 7.5 get client certificate within FTP request

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to write a custom authentication provider for FTP in IIS 7.5. I found the [**IFtpAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUser**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692879%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) Method (either native or managed) which is exactly what I need.

During the authentication the method should get the contents of a special field in the client certificate and compare it to the userName parameter provided by the AuthenticateUser Method.

My problem is now that I haven't found a way to access the client certificate within that method.

There are several solutions around for the http protocol (Request object) but not for the FTP stack.

My question is : Does anyone know how to access the client certificate within FTP during the authentication?
or
Is there a different aproach (which I missed)?